# Report Viewer DataSets

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I hope I can ask my question coherently...

I am building a Windows app that will have reports in it.  One in particular is actually an invoice.

The invoice data structure is like this:

Entity
--- Details (list of accounts for this entity)
--- Entity unique fee schedule (only one per entity)
------ Unique fee schedule details (list of itemized schedule items)

There is almost always multiple entities per invoice (customer) so I am using a tablix, grouping on the entity.  So far, so good.

Where the problem lies is getting the unique fee schedule details displaying correctly.  There could be one, or as many as 5 or 6 items within the fee schedule.  Let's say one entity has 10 accounts and 5 items in their schedule. That means there would be 10 rows in the datatable.  If I added a row for each schedule item leaving the other fields blank or repeating values, that would increase the number or rows in the datatable and also add those to the report.

So is there any way I can "nest" the schedule items within each entity without repeating rows for the accounts?  Does any of this make sense?

I'm building my datatables and dataset from objects in code.  I hope I have asked this question clearly enough but if not please let me know what else I can provide, be it code or screen shots.

Thanks in advance.